# os.rename() says file already exists, but it doesn't

Tags: python, shutil, python-os

Full error:

```py
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 
'C:\\Users\\unit0\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\EA Games\\The Sims™ 2 Ultimate Collection\\Downloads\\
test\\[Lilith] Hairs (Coolsims and Newsea)\\[Lilith] Hairs (Coolsims and Newsea)
\\\\[Lilith] Coolsims 109 3t2 DigitalAngels - Io+Pooklet' 
-> 
'C:\\Users\\unit0\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\EA Games\\The Sims™ 2 Ultimate Collection\\Downloads\\
test\\[Lilith] Hairs (Coolsims and Newsea)\\[Lilith] Hairs (Coolsims and Newsea)
\\\\LilithCoolsims1093t2DigitalAngels-IoPooklet'
```

os.rename() will give me this error even though source and destination names are different. I've tried removing a dash from the path generator (so that `\\\\` -> `\\`), but it didn't work.

shutil.move() will do the same, so I'm guessing this could have something to do with the directory's path formatting? Honestly at a loss right now.

I hope this is enough information, but I'll obviously provide more if necessary. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should try to verify that destination using `os.path.exists()` and ensure that it returns `False`.

Comment: Use `pathlib.Path` to create a path object with your absolute path. Check the `absolute()` value and see if it returns exists.  Handling windows paths is tricky at times.

Comment: Well, this is embarassing. The path, indeed, did exist (by both methods); and after re-running the script it was showing on Explorer, too. I think the function was somehow detecting a dir as a file and saving it without an extension. I'm just not 100% sure because when I deleted the "ghost" file and ran the function again, it all worked out fine. Thanks again for the replies :)